# MFC SDI changed menu using SetMenu but how to change accelerators?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a SDI application. I want to change the menu based on certain conditions in run-time.

I use this code block to change the menu and it does it's job.

```
menu = GetMenu();
SetMenu(NULL);
menu->DestroyMenu();
menu->LoadMenu(IDR_MAINFRAM_2));
SetMenu(menu);
```

My only problem is that the accelerators for the new menu does not work.
I already created an accelerator resource with ID IDR_MAINFRAM_2 but it did not solve my problem.
What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Load the accelerator and add a call to [TranslateAccelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translateacceleratorw) to your [CWnd::PreTranslateMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#pretranslatemessage) override. It's unfortunate that with all the abuse this place has promoted to do in `PreTranslateMessage`, we've apparently forgotten about when to actually use it. This is one such case.

Comment: @IInspectable MFC is already doing that (processing accelerators)

Comment: @vla Maybe so, but if you're relying on a system you do not fully comprehend, things will start to get wonky. Your [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68822436/1889329) has now started honoring two sets of accelerators. Probably not entirely what was intended.

Comment: @IInspectable the accelerator table gets `replaced` by that call, not `merged`. The replaced accelerators no longer work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight forward. Assuming you do your manipulation from the `CFrameWndEx`-derived class, just call:

```
LoadAccelTable(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAM_2));
```

MFC will process that accelerator table for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It works for the problem but there is an assertion fail calling LoadAccelTable. So I had to overcome that as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be your approach is simply not the best one. If you wanna alter the menu in run-time, my advice is for you to search on the Internet `ON_WM_INITMENU` and `ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP`

The first applies to hard-coded menus of the Frame, the second is when you are using the MFC Feature Pack, and you have declared something a `CMFCMenuBar` in your frame class. Looking to your code, in a glance, it seems you are in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late approval of the answer.

I actually used a workaround to overcome the issue and that was making sure the accelerators for different menus do not collide and let the accel table for the default menu to handle all accelerators. But I had to save menu state and avoid accelerator keys of other menus when the respective menu item was not showing.

Well that was hardly a good workaround. But I got it to work.

Today I tried to validate the answers I received to accept the correct one. The summary is:

I did not need the call to TranslateAccelerator that IInspectable stated.
Loading accelerators the way Vlad suggested does the trick, BUT there is an assertion fail when you call LoadAccelTable as it could be read from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cframewnd-class?view=msvc-160#loadacceltable) for this function which states that this function should be called only once.

So I overcame it by calling [DestroyAcceleratorTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroyacceleratortable) function and setting CFrameWnd::m_hAccelTable to NULL. before calling LoadAccelTable.

Also a sub note for those who want to change menus of SDI or MDI applications the way I did. That also cause a ,don't know why, assertion failed that was overcame by using the method suggested in this [article](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/145/Q145857/).

To sum it up, in case the provided link becomes unavailable, it says:

> 1. Create a new menu resource (IDR_MYMENU1) in the resource editor.

> 2. Add an HMENU data member to CMyDocument and override GetDefaultMenu() to
>    return this data member:

> ```
> // .h file
> //    HMENU m_hMyMenu;
> //    virtual HMENU GetDefaultMenu(); // get menu depending on state
> HMENU CMyDocument::GetDefaultMenu()
> {
>    return m_hMyMenu;    // just use original default
> }
> ```
>
> Remember to initialize this member variable to NULL either in the
> constructor   or CDocument::OnNewDocument().
>
> 3. Change and redraw the menu at the desired times. For example, when switching   between splitter panes, this is normally done in
>    CView::OnActivateView(). The   following code shows how to implement
>    it in that function.
>
>    // example within CView member function
>    ((CMyDocument*)GetDocument())->m_hMyMenu = ::LoadMenu(
>    AfxGetResourceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYMENU1));
>    ((CFrameWnd*)AfxGetMainWnd())->OnUpdateFrameMenu(NULL);
>    AfxGetMainWnd()->DrawMenuBar();
>
> Be sure to destroy the menu upon exiting the application, and avoid
> having too many menus loaded at once.
>
> Menus can also be switched simply by changing the value of
> CMDIChildWnd::m_hMenuShared (MDI) or CFrameWnd::m_hMenuDefault (SDI).
> However, using GetDefaultMenu() allows a safer method of changing the
> menus.

Also make sure not to destroy the default menu:

```
if (m_hMenuDefault != GetMenu()->m_hMenu)
    GetMenu()->DestroyMenu();
```